# How to log all exceptions to a custom logger in nest.js?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a custom logging service which outputs structured logs in a way that can be shipped to a third party log collection service.

I'm wondering what the best way to make sure that I catch all errors, from HTTP errors, to unhandled JS errors (e.g. TypeErrors, Uncaught Rejected Promises, etc), and ship them to said logger.

Most of the examples I have seen address HTTP errors only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably have a look to the uncaughtException here but it’s not related to nestjs

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

But be careful because you can corrupt the stability of your app

EDIT

You can take advantage of the global filters as describe here https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

```
App.useGlobalFilters(new MyFilter())
```

And if you want to use DI you can add them into the appModule in the providers collection as a custom provider using the token

```
Provide: APP_FILTER,
useClass: MyFilter
```

Comment: My question was related specifically with the framework Nest.JS, which has a very specific error/exception handling approach. This answer may be correct of a pure node question, but is not relevant to working inside a Nest.JS application.

Comment: The problems is you can have a globalFilter to catch all the errors using useGlobalFilters (https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) but that’s just the common error. Your question was related to all the errors which is not related to nestjs. I let you find your way in the link above.

Comment: Your edit is more relevant, and since asking my question, the approach I have taken. It does indeed catch TypeErrors, and errors that occur at boot, provided that they happen at least after the Nest app has been created.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example that catches all the exceptions, does the logging, without modifying the actual response.

```
import {
  ExceptionFilter,
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nestjs/core';

import { MyLogger } from '../modules/logger/logger.service';

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private readonly httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost) {}

  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost): void {
    const { httpAdapter } = this.httpAdapterHost;
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();

    const logger = new MyLogger();
    logger.setContext(exception['name']);
    logger.error(exception['message']);

    const httpStatus =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    httpAdapter.reply(ctx.getResponse(), exception['response'], httpStatus);
  }
}
```

Then, in `main.ts`:

```
app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter(app.get(HttpAdapterHost)));
```

Answer (score 1):

For logging purpose you can try to connect a global interceptor:

```
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new YourInterceptor());
```

In my case I used the built-in [nestjs-pino](https://github.com/iamolegga/nestjs-pino#install) logger interceptor:

```
import { Logger, LoggerErrorInterceptor } from 'nestjs-pino';

// bootstrap function
// const app = ...
const logger = app.get(Logger);

app.useLogger(logger);
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggerErrorInterceptor());
// ...rest
```